# Select * FROM WHERE 0 < 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 tables 1 for categories and the other for tasks.

Every category has a priority.

I'm trying to select the category with the highest priority that has tasks (ignoring categories that have no tasks)

The problem is that if all categories have no tasks it returns 1 result with all field null

**Category table** has the following columns:

```
id

name

priority (int beween 1 to 5)

active
```

**Tasks table** has the following columns:

```
id

name

category (id from category table)

active
```

**This is my query:**

```
select cat.*, max(cat.priority) 
from categories cat 
WHERE (
        select count(*)  AS count 
        from schedules 
        WHERE schedules.category = cat.id 
          AND schedules.active = 1
       ) > 0
```

The problem seems to be that when the result of the sub query is 0 then the main query looks like this:

```
select cat.*, min(cat.priority) 
from categories cat 
WHERE 0 < 0
```

And that returns null values

I'm working with sqlite on android

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Could you add the structure of `testView` and `schedules` ? I'd like to know if they have a common key to cook you a better query. It's impossible to come with something with what you have shown

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i have updated the question

Comment: ok that's better, I am cooking now ;) Jut to be sure: the _Tasks_ table is the `schedule` table ?

Comment: Yes, the Tasks table is the schedule table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do an `INNER JOIN` on your tasks table and that will filter the rows without tasks.

Don't use the `MAX()` aggregate function because you have no `GROUP BY` and it returns `NULL` if no values matches your filters.

If you want to keep only the highest priority, `ORDER BY` priority `DESC` and `LIMIT` the result to the first row returned

```
select cat.*
from categories cat 
INNER JOIN schedules 
   ON (schedules.category = cat.id)
WHERE schedules.active = 1
ORDER BY cat.priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This also return 1 row with null values if all schedules.active = 0

Comment: And like this? I moved the `schedules.active = 1` in the WHERE clause that should help

Comment: The fiddle helped. I have adapted my answer to what you are looking for and matching your data @אVי